# Access certain values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The following code gives me.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN']

start_date = datetime.date(2019, 1, 2)
end_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=21)
tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN']
daily_data = yf.download(tickers, start=start_date, end=end_date)
daily_data = daily_data['Adj Close'].dropna()
f = [v for _, v in daily_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))]

for i in f:
    z = i.pct_change().mean()
    print(z)
```

[image]

my question is then how do I store/ split the above output up. So for example how do i access the first 3 values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just printing the mean, you could store those values into a dataframe and then get the top 3 values using `head()`. See code below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AAPL','AMZN', 'MSFT'])

for i in f:
    z = i.pct_change().mean()
    df.loc[-1] = [z['AAPL'], z['AMZN'], z['MSFT']]
    df.index = df.index + 1 
    df = df.sort_index() 

print(df.head(3))
```

**Output:**

```
       AAPL      AMZN      MSFT
0  0.005355  0.001892  0.002672
1  0.002492  0.000307  0.002928
2  0.004748  0.001112  0.002121
```